# Code coverage in Production combined with coverage in tests

Tags: python, profiling, code-coverage

Imagine you have a large legacy Python code base which runs in production since several years.

The code coverage of tests is low (around 50%).

To prioritize the code parts which should be covered first, I would like to combine the code which gets executed in production with the code coverage of the tests.

I think there is a lot of old code, which does not get executed in production any more.

Is there a way to combine results of a sampling profiler running on production with the coverage of the tests?

Commercial solutions are welcome, too.

Goal: I want to see which lines get often executed in production, but are missing a test.

Comment: [`coverage.py`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/)?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński how can I get the lines which the interpreter executes regularly on the production site with coverage.py?